# Complete set of vectors vs basis of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the difference between a complete set of vectors and a basis of vectors. Do they not both mean that an arbitrary vector in the vector space can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors?

Comment: "Complete" is an uncommon word in this context. I think you mean "spanning".

Comment: It is also possible that "complete" here is referring to the condition that any Cauchy sequence on a vector space has a limit in the space. Example, Banach space.  It's hard to tell without reading exactly what you've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **basis** is a collection of linear independent and spanning vectors which means they are each a linear combo of the set V.

A **complete set of vectors** or just a set of vectors is a basis. They are just two different ways to say the same thing.

Comment: If you say linear independent vectors are "each a linear combo of one another" you mean something else, don't you ?

Comment: What do you mean something else? That is the definition of a basis.

Comment: In a basis, no vector is a linear combination of the other ones.

Comment: I edited my answer now does it make sense to you.