# Complete set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The following excerpt is from the book Operators, Functions, and Systems, Vol. 1 by Nikolai K. Nikolski, [pages 216-217](https://books.google.com/books?id=PdDDAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA216)

[image]

[image]

What is a "complete set of vectors" in the proof of Lemma 2.4.4?

Im putting my money on

"A subset of the basis which is linearly independent and whose span is dense is called a complete set"

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669341/complete-set-of-vectors-vs-basis-of-vectors

Comment: @Rohan That post is just confusing.

Comment: What is the context? What book are you reading?

Comment: Operator, functions and systems: An easy reading, Nikolski. We are in the Hardy space basically.

Comment: It is always recommended to [include sufficient context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) into the question. (For example, it would be better to include the name of the book in the question, not only in the comment where it is much less noticeable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from this [link](http://www.int.washington.edu/users/dbkaplan/324_01/DiracNotation.pdf), it seems that a set of basis vectors is said *complete* if and only if its elements span the all space.

E.g. in $\Bbb R^{3}$ seen as a vector space of $\Bbb R$, we have the standard basis $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. The family $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ of basis vectors is not complete as it does not span all of $\Bbb R^{3}$.

In finite dimensional settings, the terms "basis" and "complete set" are equivalent. It may have a subtlety when the set is infinite dimensional. Anyway, for a book about functional analysis, it seems to be a confusing terminology, as completeness (in the [topological sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space)) is an important property in many functional spaces.

For what you are "putting your money on", I guess it would make sense but asking that they are linearly independent is useless as, if they are a subset of the basis, they *must* be linearly independent.

You might be interested in [this question from the physics community](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98462/use-of-complete-as-in-complete-set-of-states-or-complete-basis) addressing the different notions of "completeness" for a family of vectors.

Comment: regarding on what I was putting my money on. Well we only ask for this set to be dense not all of the space.

Comment: Actually, a [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) is called total when the set of all linear combinations of the elements of the Schauder basis is dense.

But does one of the definition of "complete set" given in the physics question make sense w.r.t. the situation in your book?

Comment: I just realised the space is finite dimensional..which makes the infinite setting unnessesary..he might have kept the termenology tho. I think i finished the details now in this proof and I only use that any lineary indep. set of n vectors in dim=m<n must be lin. dept. As I see it he only uses the equations to get a family of lin. indept. vectors which must be a basis.

Comment: With regards to finite dimensional spaces: in your example, the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is not a basis, as - by definition - a basis for a space $V$ is a set of linearly independent vectors that span the space. Thus, it is nonsensical to speak of "basis" vectors that do not span a set. In short, "a set of vectors that span a space" = "basis vectors" = "complete set".

Comment: @DylanR I understand your point. However we can speak of “basis vectors” which would mean “a subset of a basis”. For example $\{(1,0,0),(2,0,0)\}$ cannot be called basis vectors because the elements of this set are linearly dependent. However $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ are basis vectors (which means that together with an appropriate third vector they form a basis). This is consistent in my opinion (and I have often seen such a way of talking).